# get update value after an updateOne()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

is it possible to get all updated value/value where there is a diff after a call of updateOne()

```
 _.each(gameResult, function(gameResult){
    bulk.find({"user" : gameResult.user, "section" : gameResult.section , "code" : gameResult.code}).upsert().updateOne(gameResult);
  })
```

imagine my value in the db before the update are :

```
1, 1, 1, 1
```

gameResult is :

```
1, 2, 1 , 3
```

So my db is updated :     1, 2, 1, 3

Is it possible to get all value who are changed, so here how can i get my two object 2 and 3 cause i need it in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/).

This performs an update while also returning the existing document from the database. By default, this method returns the document *before* the changes are applied (this behavior can be changed with the `new:true` option). So you can easily compare the returned document with your local document to find the differences.

Unfortunately findAndModify isn't supported by bulk operations, so you need to do it document-by-document.

Comment: I see, it can be a solution. I've just create a new Promise to get updated data and compare it to the old (gameResult).

Comment: Looks like this is deprecated for node driver now?  Node docs say `use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead`. 
 http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findAndModify